# All testcase should run in gitlab instead 1st one failed

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I was setting up a gitlab environment. After each push 1 am running 5 test cases. But if the any of the test cases is falling other testcase are skipped. 
I want to run all the cases. Because they are independent to each other.

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - build
  - unit_test_1
  - unit_test_2
  - unit_test_3

job1:
    stage: build
    script:
        - bash build.sh

job2:
    stage: unit_test_1
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_1.sh

job3:
    stage: unit_test_2
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_2.sh

job4:
    stage: unit_test_3
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_3.sh
```

If uint_test_1.sh is failing. Other tests are skipped.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`when`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#when) property to make your jobs run every time, regardless of the status of jobs from prior stages of the build.

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

job1:
    stage: build
    script:
        - bash build.sh

job2:
    stage: test
    when: always
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_1.sh

job3:
    stage: test
    when: always
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_2.sh

job4:
    stage: test
    when: always
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_3.sh
```

Also, if you want to make sure you never have jobs running in parallel then you can configure your runners with concurrency limits.

Configuring it [globally](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-global-section) will limit all your runners to only run 1 job concurrently between all runners.

Configuring it [per runner](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runners-section) will limit that runner to only run 1 job concurrently per build token.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

job1:
    stage: build
    script:
        - bash build.sh

job2:
    stage: test
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_1.sh

job3:
    stage: test
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_2.sh

job4:
    stage: test
    script:
        - bash ./unit_test_3.sh
```

The documentation say:

> The ordering of elements in stages defines the ordering of builds' execution:
>
> Builds of the same stage are run in parallel.
> Builds of the next stage are run after the jobs from the previous stage complete successfully.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#stages

To run in parallel you have to put the same stage name
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/pipelines.html#pipelines

Comment: Yes I have tried this. But it will execute all jobs job2,job3 and job4. I don't want to execute in parallel. It will created resource crunch. I want to execute all script. But If the first one is not successful then it is skipping other stages.

Comment: In this case you probably need `allow_failure`https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#allow_failure

Comment: (I don't know how to edit a comment) if you want one stage called `test` and run all tests jobs (sequentially : not in parrallel) even if some fails you will need to add `dependencies` and `allow_failure` in the solution that i suggest you https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#dependencies docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#allow_fa‌​ilure

Comment: You can add all the jobs to the same stage, but still prevent them from running in parallel by adding a concurrent job limit of 1 to the runner. You can limit it to [1 per runner with `limit`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runners-section) , or [1 for all runners with `concurrent`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-global-section).